# Play SoundCloud links through Soundmanager2

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

I'm using the Soundmanager Mp3 Button on my site. However, I'd like to use the Soundcloud Api to stream tracks through Soundmanager instead of hosting MP3's. Basically, I'd like to stream a Soundcloud link through the Soundmanager button. Possible?

I've tried creating a jQuery loop (below) but still haven't had any luck.

```
<ol>
<li><a class="sm2_button" href="http://soundcloud.com/....">Track Title</a>
</li>
</ol>
```

and the jQuery

```
$("ol a").each(function()
    { 
        var thisLink = $(this);                         
        var track_url = this.href;                      // save href value of each link to 'track_url' i.e. soundcloud.com/...
        this.href = this.href.replace(track_url, "#");  // replace href value with '#'
        var consumer_key = 'My Consumer Key';
            // now resolve the stream_url through Soundcloud's getJSON method
        $.when($.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=' + track_url + '&format=json&consumer_key=' + consumer_key + '&callback=?', function(track) {
            url = track.stream_url + '?consumer_key=' + consumer_key;   
            })).done(function() {
                // and place an 'onclick' on each link
                $(thisLink).attr('onclick', "if (basicMP3Player.lastSound) { basicMP3Player.lastSound.stop(); } document.getElementById('mp3').type='audio/mpeg'; document.getElementById('mp3').href = '" + url + "'; basicMP3Player.handleClick({target: document.getElementById('mp3')});");
            });
    });
```

Comment: Some of the topics on the SoundManager forum might help you: https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/searches?query=soundcloud&x=0&y=0&style=topics

Comment: Tried that as well. Going crazy over here haha. Plays perfectly when linking to a hosted mp3 but not soundcloud link

Answer (score 5):

This was driving me nuts too.  After a bunch of digging I was able to get it to work if I specified an mp3 mimetype in the link:

```
<ol>
    <li><a type="audio/mp3" class="sm2_button" href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/49349198/stream?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID">Track Title</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using the SoundCloud [Javascript SDK](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks), which'll take care of most of this for you.

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html",
});


SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
  sound.play();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the script above but still cannot seem to get it to work. Is there a class I should be adding to the anchor? <a class="sc" href="http://soundcloud.com...>Track Title</a>

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and thought I had it...anyone see anything?

```
 <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <script>
    SC.initialize({
      client_id: "My Consumer Key",
      redirect_uri: "My Redirect",
    });

    SC.get("/users/MYUSERID/tracks", {limit: 1000}, function(tracks){
      alert("Latest track: " + tracks[0].title);
    });

    $(".sm2_button").live("click", function(sound){
         sound.play();
      });

    </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".sm2_button").each(function()
        { 
            var thisLink = $(this);                         
            var track_url = this.href;                      // save href value of each link to 'track_url' i.e. soundcloud.com/...
            this.href = this.href.replace(track_url, "#");  // replace href value with '#'
            var consumer_key = 'My Consumer Key';
                // now resolve the stream_url through Soundcloud's getJSON method
            $.when($.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=' + track_url + '&format=json&consumer_key=' + consumer_key + '&callback=?', function(track) {
                url = track.stream_url + '?consumer_key=' + consumer_key;   
                })).done(function() {
                    // and place an 'onclick' on each link
                    $(thisLink).attr('onclick', "if (basicMP3Player.lastSound) { basicMP3Player.lastSound.stop(); } document.getElementById('mp3').type='audio/mpeg'; document.getElementById('mp3').href = '" + url + "'; basicMP3Player.handleClick({target: document.getElementById('mp3')});");
                });
        }); 
          }); </script>
```